# Using FOR statement with Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

Can I use the For Statement with Logstash?

And if so, how?

I know we can use the IF statement and I've been using it successfully

Comment: What is it you wish to loop across?  With what results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can use 'RUBY' plugin and write the ruby code to do your For statement.

```
filter 
{ 
    ruby {
         code => "
              #RUBY CODE HERE
         "
    }
}
```